# Need to Protect JSON file from accessing

Tags: c#, json

I have Created a C# Desktop Windows form Application and I have created a setup for that.  In the `C:\Programs  files` app folder I have a JSON file. I need to protect it from accessing by anyone (I need to protect the data). What should I do?

Comment: You will not be able to stop people from accessing a file, if the file contains settings for your app and your want to stop them from changing it, you could set the Read-Only flag.
If your file contains secure data, which should not be seen by anyone, you could just encrypt your file with basically any encryption algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If the intruder have access to the computer with the Administrator rights (or even  more - a physical access to the hardware), then any protection will be useless.

You can use some kind of encryption, code obfuscation and some anti-debugging techniques to make it harder to retrieve the data, but qualified intruder with the appropriate access level will be able to access the data in the moment when you will decrypt it.

The only working way is to completely remove the secret data from the client's computer and move it to the your secure server alongside with the processing of such a data. So, client sends the inputs to your server, the server performs the processing using the secret data and sends back ready-to-use results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: it's impossible to make it un-breakable - I won't argue on this. Then you can simply encrypt it with a simple Blowfish algorithm and keep the key hardcoded.

You can use a more secure algorithm if you want so.

Comment: Will this encrypt and decrypt will slowdown the runtime?

Comment: Of course, the stronger the encryption is, the longer will be the slowdown. But will be on the order of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use a binary serialization format instead of json. This will make it much harder to understand and decode. Or just hardcode the data instead. Most people lack the knowledge to do anything meaningfull with a binary chunk of data, or an assembly for that matter.

A more complicated solution would be to [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) the data, as this would allow you to only hardcode the key. A related alternative is Encryption. Encryption is sufficient but not necessary for ensuring the integrity of the data, but is not really more difficult to apply, see [encrypting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data).

Whatever you do you cannot really prevent a sufficiently determined and knowledgeable attacker. It is possible to decompile the program and extract or replace any secrets therein. The only truly secure way would be to prevent access to the files in the first place, by moving it to the web for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and decided to encrypt the data.

I used the package "AuthenticatedEncryption" (available from NuGet ) and could hard-code the key in my code.

NuGet:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/AuthenticatedEncryption/
Guthub:  https://github.com/trustpilot/nuget-authenticated-encryption

I can do this, as my main purpose is more to make the data unreadable to users and I don't expect it to be unbreakable.
Even so, I change the key every few releases.

For my ~70Kb JSON file I only load it once at the start of the program, so performance is not a problem.  Not that I anyway notice anything!